# Dynamically Added ListView only displays 1 item

Tags: android, android-listview, dynamic-data

I have an activity that shows customer information. All the controls are drawn dynamically as the design for the screen is controlled by a central SQL database. (IE screen position, editable and mandatory) so there is no XML for the design.

Now so far everything I have done has worked very well until I came to try adding a ListView object to list the customers communication data. (IE a list of phone numbers, emails, fax numbers or website URLs)

This List view is added correctly and the first row of data is displayed but I cannot seem to get the anymore rows to display.

The items are added into a table row and these are then added onto a table layout. Could this be the problem? However when adding the ListView item this is first added to a RelativeLayout item so this should allow more than one line to be displayed?!

Any Ideas why this could be occurring? I have checked the values of my array and I definitely have more than one item in it.

The following is the Activities onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    model = SharedModel.getInstance();
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    LinearLayout baseLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    baseLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    // add the customer name and number field.
    // NOTE: We will always require this widget regardless of dialog design fields
    tvCustomerNameNumber = new TextView(this);
    tvCustomerNameNumber.setTextSize(20);
    baseLayout.addView(tvCustomerNameNumber);

    // buttons
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams alignBotton = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    LinearLayout buttons = new LinearLayout(this);
    buttons.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    alignBotton.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, baseLayout.getId());

    // button edit
    Button edit = new Button(this);
    edit.setId(EDIT_BUTTON_ID);
    edit.setText(dbHelper.getActivityString(dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(), model.getUserLang().getLanguage().GetCodeId(), "buttonEdit", 1001000));
    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setButtonsEnabled(false, true, true);
            setControlsEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    buttons.addView(edit);

    // button save
    Button save = new Button(this);
    save.setId(SAVE_BUTTON_ID);
    save.setText(dbHelper.getActivityString(dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(), model.getUserLang().getLanguage().GetCodeId(), "buttonSave", 1001000));
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                saveCustomer();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    buttons.addView(save);

    // button cancel
    Button cancel = new Button(this);
    cancel.setId(CANCEL_BUTTON_ID);
    cancel.setText(dbHelper.getActivityString(dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(), model.getUserLang().getLanguage().GetCodeId(), "buttonCancel", 1001000));
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                cancelChanges();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    buttons.addView(cancel);

    // add the buttons
    baseLayout.addView(buttons);

    // build up the table of controls
    TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);

    // get the dialog design json array for customer information
    dialogFields = model.getDialogDesignFields();   

    // reset the field type indexes
    addedIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    addedCodeIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    addedDateIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    addedTextIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    addedListIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    mandatoryIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // for each control in the array
    for(int i=0;i<=model.getDialogDesignFields().length() - 1; i++) {
        try {
            // if the control is for the customer page
            if(dialogFields.getJSONObject(i).get("formname").equals("CustomerInformation")){
                handleField(tl, dialogFields.getJSONObject(i));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       

    // Scroll view.
    // NOTE: We will always need this widget to enable us to scroll the page
    // if too many items are added for the display size
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    sv.addView(tl);
    baseLayout.addView(sv);

    // set the content view
    this.setContentView(baseLayout);
    // make sure we are not in edit mode
    setButtonsEnabled(true, false, false);
    setControlsEnabled(false);
    setResult(0); 
}
```

And now the handleField method that decides what to do with the field im adding:

```
private void handleField(TableLayout tl, final JSONObject field) throws JSONException {

    // get field index
    int id = field.getInt("viewindex") + 1;
    final String name = field.getString("name");

    // if the name = CustomerAddressID don't do anything
    if(name.equals("CustomerAddressID") != true) {
        // if the name is not equal to CustomerCommunicationID
        if(name.equals("CustomerCommunicationID") == false) {
            if(id > 0) {
                // create and add controls
                // add the field index to the 
                addedIndexes.add(id);
                // layout parameters
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams alignRight = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                // if the field is mandatory
                if(field.getInt("mandatory") == 1) {
                    TextView mandatory = new TextView(this);
                    mandatory.setText("*");
                    tl.addView(mandatory);
                    mandatoryIndexes.add(id);
                }           

                // field name description
                TextView fn = new TextView(this);
                fn.setId(id + 1000);
                fn.setText(dbHelper.getActivityString(dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(), model.getUserLang().getLanguage().GetCodeId(), name, 1000030));
                tl.addView(fn);             

                // create a table row 
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                tr.setId(id + 10000);
                tl.addView(tr);

                // create a relative layout
                RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
                rl.setId(id + 100000);
                rl.setTag(field);
                rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myborder);

                // if the control is not disabled
                if(field.getInt("disabled") == 0) {

                    // so we are adding a listener
                    // if the name is code we are adding to code indexes 
                    if(name.endsWith("CODE") == true | name.equals("PreferredVisitDay")) {                      
                        addedCodeIndexes.add(id);
                    } else if (name.endsWith("DATE") == true) {
                        addedDateIndexes.add(id);                       
                    } else {
                        addedTextIndexes.add(id);
                    }           

                    // add a listener
                    rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // show the code picker for customer group
                            JSONObject field = (JSONObject) v.getTag(); 
                            try {
                                prepareDialog(field);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }                               
                        }
                    });

                    // image view           
                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                    iv.setId(id + 1000000);
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.edit16x16);
                    iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    alignRight.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, iv.getId());
                    rl.addView(iv, alignRight);
                }                   

                tl.addView(rl);
                // fieldValue
                TextView fv = new TextView(this);
                fv.setId(id + 10000000);
                fv.setTextSize(18);
                rl.addView(fv);

            }
        } else {
            if(id > 0) {
                addedIndexes.add(id);

                // field name description
                TextView fn = new TextView(this);
                fn.setId(id + 1000);
                fn.setText(dbHelper.getActivityString(dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(), model.getUserLang().getLanguage().GetCodeId(), name, 1000030));
                tl.addView(fn);             

                // create a table row 
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                tr.setId(id + 10000);
                tl.addView(tr);

                // create a relative layout
                RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
                rl.setId(id + 100000);
                rl.setTag(field);
                rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myborder);

                tl.addView(rl);
                // list view
                ListView lv = new ListView(this);
                lv.setId(id + 10000000);
                lv.setTag(field);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
                        try {
                            communicationClicked(arg0, view, position, id, field);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }           
                    }
                });
                rl.addView(lv);
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

The ListView Item is added in the second block of code with the following code:

```
// list view
ListView lv = new ListView(this);
lv.setId(id + 10000000);
lv.setTag(field);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
        try {
            communicationClicked(arg0, view, position, id, field);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
});
rl.addView(lv);
```

Finally the List view is populated with the following code:

```
} else if (name.equals("CustomerCommunicationID")){
    // set communications value
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(index + 10000000);
    // create an array adapter with the customer type data array
    ArrayAdapter<Communication> communicationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Communication>(this, R.layout.communication_menu_item, currentCustomer.getCustomerCommunications());
    // assign the my customers list control the array adapter
    lv.setAdapter(communicationAdapter);
    Log.i(TAG, "Communications Assigned");
} else {
```

I have done a test and added a Listview at the top of my application and set the listadapter to my array and all the lines are displayed.

So looks like Its to do with the Table rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some research I have found that its not good practice to place a `ListView` inside a another scrollable item.

The following link discusses this:

[Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Answer (score 1):

Do not put ListView in a ScrollView.

Comment: Since I was new to stackoverflow, I couldn't up vote the answer; but I wanted to make people know that the solution works. Sorry about the duplicate answer!